# F-string are putting the "" inside a {}

Tags: python, f-string

My Code:

```
videos = []
for keys in data:
    videos.append({f"'path: 'videos/{filename}.mp4', 'description': '{filename}'"},)
```

The problem:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elvzM.png)

As you can see the f-string is putting the "" inside the {} but i dont want that

Comment: Your code should contain a [mcve], along with expected and actual output. Use text, not images. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were creating a set like this:

```py
{f"'path: 'videos/{filename}.mp4', 'description': '{filename}'"}
```

This makes the entire thing one big string inside a set. Do this instead:

```py
videos = []
for keys in data:
    videos.append({'path': f'videos/{filename}.mp4', 'description': filename})
```

Comment: Well, you're right, I wasn't even thinking well. Thanks